# performance of average on python list. sum(l)/len(l) vs numpy.mean(l)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, mean

Was fooling around about what is the best way to calculate a mean of a list in python. Although I thought that numpy as optimized My results show that you shouldn't use numpy when it comes to this. I was wondering why and how python achieve this performance.

So basically I am trying to figure out how come native python is faster than numpy.

My code for testing:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import timeit

def average_native(l):
    return sum(l)/len(l)


def average_np(l):
    return np.mean(l)


def test_time(func, arg):
    starttime = timeit.default_timer()
    for _ in range(500):
        func(arg)
    return (timeit.default_timer() - starttime) / 500


for i in range(1, 7):
    numbers = []
    for _ in range(10**i):
        numbers.append(random.randint(0, 100))
    print("for " + str(10**i) + " numbers:")
    print(test_time(average_native, numbers))
    print(test_time(average_np, numbers))
```

The results:

```
for 10 numbers:
2.489999999999992e-07
8.465800000000023e-06
for 100 numbers:
8.554000000000061e-07
1.3220000000000009e-05
for 1000 numbers:
7.2817999999999495e-06
6.22666e-05
for 10000 numbers:
6.750499999999993e-05
0.0005553966000000001
for 100000 numbers:
0.0006954238
0.005352444999999999
for 1000000 numbers:
0.007034196399999999
0.0568878216
```

BTW I was running same code in c++ and was surprised to see that the python code is faster. test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

float calculate_average(std::vector<int> vec_of_num)
{
    double sum=0;
    uint64_t cnt=0;
    for(auto & elem : vec_of_num)
    {
        cnt++;
        sum = sum + elem;     
    }
    return sum / cnt;
}
int main()
{
    // This program will create same sequence of
    // random numbers on every program run
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
       vec.push_back(rand());
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
       calculate_average(vec);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> float_ms = end - start;

    std::cout << "calculate_average() elapsed time is " << float_ms.count()/500 << " ms )" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

results:

```
calculate_average() elapsed time is 11.2082 ms )
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit**: I was running the c++ code on an online compiler (probebly without any optimization). Also it isn't the same Hardware, and how know what is going on it that server. After running and compiling the code in my device the code is much faster.

**Edit2**: So I changed the code for a numpy array in the numpy function and we do see that for smaller array/list the native python is better, however after around 1000 values numpy is preforming better. I don't really understand why. which optimizations numpy have that produce these results?

new results:

```
for 10 numbers:
2.4540000000000674e-07
6.722200000000012e-06
for 100 numbers:
8.497999999999562e-07
6.583400000000017e-06
for 1000 numbers:
6.990799999999964e-06
7.916000000000034e-06
for 10000 numbers:
6.61604e-05
1.5475799999999985e-05
for 100000 numbers:
0.0006671193999999999
8.412259999999994e-05
for 1000000 numbers:
0.0068192092
0.0008199298000000005
```

Maybe I need to restart this question :)

Comment: how did you compile the code? C++ code compiled without optimizations can be arbitrarily slow

Comment: np.mean(l) is going to get all the numbers from python and copy them to numpy because they're in a python list not a numpy array. What happens if you make the numpy array first, and then call np.mean 500 times?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein For what sizes?

Comment: @KellyBundy Your point (as usual) is that numpy performs better when its arrays (in this case) are large. If the array/list has a length of 100,000 items, numpy outperforms pure Python (as one would expect). But with fewer elements (e.g., 1,000) numpy underperforms

Comment: It would be interesting to add [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to your timing comparision.

Comment: RE the edit, have you tried running one of the optimized versions of the C++ code suggested in the answers? Your version is making an extra copy which probably takes the majority of the time.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Yes, with half of their tested sizes, it's not true, so it seemed like an odd thing to say...

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Just for you: 10: 1*10**-5,  100 3*10**-5, 1000: 3*10**-4, 10000: 3*10**-3, 100000: 0.03, 1000000: 0.35

Comment: I find scientific notation rather inconvenient to read here. [Proposal](https://tio.run/##hZHdasMwDIXv8xQiUOp0WZp07IfCnmSMoq1KZ2gUoziFPn0mNw7NSmG@MbY@nXMsu7P/aflpGGzjWvEgyPu2SeKJ@8adATtgN11525D1SbKnGvBEggfaMXp7InPMtgnoEvK9MHR9o1frI7FuyU2Hu6XZFQ0hG5xQT53fBTdT9/ydA8ohdnQexYcKvMc4hTZgfxx5MdkFq1uBHVgObzqQeS7L2H8pqqYJkvMMy8VbsamXsABj7gvD49U9gzWoKKygopeQOhjaq2GVw2t01Dl@kXSa9@PzXraqXK3sLF3kC3SOeG/GTynCZtmbModKHzNGRxXV2aEInk3sGytOApwGqxQeNLdEHz2kk8U2ncPXmf/92nzCs39oNyOH4Rc) (see the output section).

Comment: I did include some benchmarks in my answer to shed some light on the time cost of the `list` to `np.ndarray` conversion, as well as `statistics.mean` @WarrenWeckesser

Answer (score 2):

C++ is much much slower than it needs to be.

First, for the C++ code, you're copying the `vector`, which is probably what's taking most of the time. You want to write:

```
float calculate_average(const std::vector<int>& vec_of_num)
```

instead of

```
float calculate_average(std::vector<int> vec_of_num)
```

In order to avoid making the copy.

Second, make sure you've compiled with optimizations on.

For the `numpy` version, you're doing an extra conversion, which slows you down.

[From the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
a: array_like
Array containing numbers whose mean is desired. If a is not an array, a conversion is attempted.
```

So whatever is passed to `numpy.mean` is first converted into a `numpy.array`, then the mean is computed. Making the Numpy array is probably taking a good portion of your time here.

I'd suggest doing two more benchmarks and seeing how they compare with what you already have:

(1) C++ version without the copying, as I describe above, and make sure optimizations are on.
(2) Numpy version where you pass in a numpy array instead of a Python list.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`numpy.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) is doing a lot more than what `sum()` and `len()` is doing, that is why it is so "slow".

The kind of functionalities included in `np.mean()` is essentially what it makes it a [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html), and especially the support for n-dimensional arrays.

However, the largest contributor to the speed difference between the naïve implementation and `np.mean()` is actually converting the `list` to a NumPy array.

Consider the following ways to compute the average:

- this is essentially what you think it is super-fast

```py
def mean_naive(seq):
    return sum(seq) / len(seq)
```

- this is a numeric-safe implementation that is present in the standard Python library

```py
import statistics


def mean_st(seq):
    return statistics.mean(seq)
```

- this uses the NumPy `mean()` function:

```py
import numpy as np


def mean_np(seq):
    return np.mean(seq)
```

- this is the same as the naïve approach but a conversion to a NumPy array is performed to factor out the NumPy array conversion cost:

```py
import numpy as np


def mean_naive_conv(seq):
    np.array(seq)  # the result of the conversion is not used!
    return sum(seq) / len(seq)
```

- this is a Numba-accelerated version of the naïve approach acting on NumPy arrays. The Numba acceleration essentially converts the Python code to *optimized* C++ code via just-in-time compilation with `llvm`. If `sum() / len()` is *faster-than-C*, then `mean_naive_conv()` should outperform this one.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def mean_naive_nb(seq):
    sum_ = 0
    for x in seq:
        sum_ += x
    return sum_ / len(seq)


def mean_naive_np_nb(seq):
    seq = np.array(seq)
    return mean_naive_nb(seq)
```

However, when we benchmarks these with the following code:

```py
import random


funcs = (
    mean_naive, mean_st, mean_np, mean_naive_conv, mean_naive_np_nb, only_conv)

timings = {}
for k in range(1, 20):
    n = 2 ** k
    seq = tuple(random.random() for _ in range(n))
    print(f"n = {n}, k = {k}")
    timings[n] = []
    base = funcs[0](seq)
    for func in funcs:
        res = func(seq)  # this ensures that JIT-ted code is compiled before benchmarking
        is_good = np.allclose(base, res)
        timed = %timeit -r 4 -n 8 -q -o func(seq)
        timing = timed.best * 1e6
        timings[n].append(timing)
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_good!s:>5}  {timing:10.3f} µs")
```

to be plotted with:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=[func.__name__ for func in funcs]).transpose()
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', ylim=[0, 40000])

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

[image: bm]

and with:

```py
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', ylim=[0, 600], xlim=[0, 9000])

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

[image]

(for some zooming on the smaller input sizes)

we can observe:

- The `statistics`-based approach is the slowest by far and large
- The naïve approach is the fastest by far and large
- When comparing the all the methods that do have a type conversion from Python `list` to NumPy array:

  - `np.mean()` is the fastest for larger input sizes, likely because it is compiled with specific optimizations (I'd speculate making optimal use of SIMD instructions); for smaller inputs, the running time is dominated by the overhead for supporting all `ufunc` functionalities
  - the Numba-accelerated version is the fastest for medium input sizes; for very small inputs, the running time is lengthened by the small, roughly constant, overhead of calling a Numba function
  - for very small inputs the `sum() / len()` eventually gets to be the fastest

This indicates that `sum() / len()` is essentially slower than *optimized* C++ code acting on arrays.

Comment: Maybe clarify the extra work that mean is doing, if you have details on this?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I think have given enough clarification now

Comment: running your numba function give me different results. it have the worst timing by far. I am unfamiliar with numba package so I just copy your numba function and run it with my test_time function.

Comment: @Avizipi Are you running it once outside of your timing framework? Otherwise you are including the compilation time in your tests.

Comment: I did.
Can you explain why your maen_naive_conv is faster than mean_np code for smaller lists?

Comment: @Avizipi It lacks all the code to ensure to support for `ufunc` parameters. This is essentially a constant (read `O(1)`)overhead that becomes less and less relevant as the input size grows.

Comment: @norok2 I am getting an error  File "XXXXXX/scratch_5.py", line 47
    timed = %timeit -r 4 -n 8 -q -o func(seq)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need to use IPython instead of Python to use `%timeit` magic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246032/discussion-between-avizipi-and-norok2).

Answer (score 0):

My code is at the end.

**Conclusion/answer to the question**

From the tests results below, the Numpy methods (at least for computing the mean) are definitely faster than the Python built-in methods, **as long as you are working with big enough lists or arrays**.

However, the Python built-in method I tested can outperform the Numpy one for very short (1D-)lists or (1D-)arrays. Here it happens for lists/arrays containing less than ~150 numbers : so you must be aware of it!

[@norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72803359/22908125) 's above answer explains this behavior.

To no surprise, you can also see that the relative performances between each method remain consistent, no matter how many times the functions are called.

**Method**

As I went through a tutorial about Numpy, I read that with increasing size, Numpy arrays manipulations can be up to 30 times faster than the same operation with built-in Python list operations.

So, out of curiosity, I made a script which measure the execution time of 2 fonctions (through a decorator) :

1. The Numpy method for computing (here 1D-)array mean:

```
    def mean_array(array):
      return np.mean(array)
```

2. The way to compute the mean with Python built-in functions:

```
    def mean_list(liste):
     return sum(liste)/len(liste)
```

*Randomness, reliability*

With the `random` module, I generated `maxnsize` lists `income`. Each list `income[i]` contains `nsize[i]` randomly generated numbers between 1400 and 10000 (I figured a case with the incomes from `nsize[i]` financial operations in a year).

Note that `maxnsize`  is the number of times each function (time) test were repeated. This gave me a sample of `maxnsize` measurements of the execution time of the above functions, so I could infer a statistical mean and standard deviation to enforce the reliability of my tests.

To further improve the robustness of my conclusions and enforce a stress test of comparing the functions at different list sizes (hence scattering the time execution scales), I also randomized each `nsize[i]` to be between `1` and a parameter `nmaxoperations`.

Thus, before we proceed to measure the functions performances : all the incomes, the lists containing them, and the size of each list are randomly generated using `numpy.randint`.

I tested those parameters :

1. `maxnsize =` `1e3`,`1e4`,`1e5`
2. For each `maxnsize`, I tested `nmaxoperations =` `10`,`1e2`,..,`1e6`,`1e7`

I note `x` the time ratio of the Python method over the Numpy one.

**Results**

- `maxnsize = 1000`

  - `nmaxoperations=`

    - `10`  : `x=0.2723±0.0654`
    - `1e2` : `x=0.7056±0.3035`
    - `1e3` : `x=4.4767±2.6933`
    - `1e4` : `x=23.670±11.838`
    - `1e5` : `x=42.059±14.877`
- `maxnsize = 10000`

  - `nmaxoperations=`

    - `10`  : `x=0.2290±0.0854`
    - `1e2` : `x=0.7654±0.3593`
    - `1e3` : `x=4.6912±2.9002`
    - `1e4` : `x=23.052±11.884`
    - `1e5` : `x=44.127±14.886`
- `maxnsize = 100000`

  - `nmaxoperations=`

    - `10`  : `x=0.2854±0.1108`
    - `1e2` : `x=0.7566±0.3488`
    - `1e3` : `x=4.6768±3.0187`
    - `1e4` : `x=23.835±11.870`
    - `1e5` : `x=43.780±14.326`

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import time

def measure_time(fonction):

    def modified_function(element):

        time_start = time.time() 
        returned = fonction(element) 
        time_end    = time.time()
        time_execution = time_end - time_start
        return time_execution, returned
    
    return modified_function



@measure_time
def mean_array(array):
    return np.mean(array)

@measure_time
def mean_liste(liste):
    return sum(liste)/len(liste)

maxnsize = 100
nmaxoperations = 1000  
nsize = np.random.randint(1,high=nmaxoperations,size=maxnsize)
time_liste = []
time_array = []
ratio_performances = []
means_liste = []
means_array = []
for i in range(0,maxnsize):
    income = np.random.randint(1400,high=10000,size=nsize[i]) 
    perf_array = tuple(mean_array(income)) 
    perf_liste = tuple(mean_liste(income)) 
    time_liste.append(perf_liste[0])
    means_liste.append(perf_liste[1])
    time_array.append(perf_array[0])
    means_array.append(perf_array[1])
    ratio_performances.append(time_liste[i]/time_array[i]) 


time_mean_liste = np.mean(time_liste)
time_mean_array = np.mean(time_array)
time_std_liste = np.std(time_liste)
time_std_array = np.std(time_array)
mean_income_liste = np.mean(means_liste)
mean_income_array = np.mean(means_array)
mean_std_liste = np.std(means_liste)
mean_std_array = np.std(means_array)
ratio_performances_mean = np.mean(ratio_performances)
ratio_performances_std = np.std(ratio_performances)

print(u"With Python\'s list : mean = {}\u00B1{} computed within {}\u00B1{} s".format(mean_income_liste,
                                                                                    mean_std_liste,
                                                                                    time_mean_liste,
                                                                                    time_std_liste))

print(u"With Numpy\'s array : mean = {}\u00B1{} computed within {}\u00B1{} s".format(mean_income_array,
                                                                                    mean_std_array,
                                                                                    time_mean_array,
                                                                                    time_std_array))

print(u"Numy took {}\u00B1{} less time to compute mean thant with Python built-in methods".format(ratio_performances_mean,ratio_performances_std))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are copying the array for each call to average which takes a lot of extra time.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>


//!! pass vector by reference to avoid copies!!!!
double calculate_average(const std::vector<int>& vec_of_num)
{
    return static_cast<double>(std::accumulate(vec_of_num.begin(), vec_of_num.end(), 0)) / static_cast<double>(vec_of_num.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 generator(1); // static std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 0,1000 };

    // This program will create same sequence of
    // random numbers on every program run
    std::vector<int> values(1000000);

    for (auto& value : values)
    {
        value = distribution(generator);
    }

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double sum{ 0.0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        // force compiler to use average so it can't be optimized away
        sum += calculate_average(values);
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> float_ms = end - start;

    // force compiler to use sum so it can't be optimized away
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "calculate_average() elapsed time is " << float_ms.count() / 500 << " ms )" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Fixed typo (and time went down to 2e-08 ms ) so it really helps ;)

Comment: What's the time with copying?

Comment: See top of solution the time with copying is still there about 0.6ms.  
The calculated averages are very close to 500 (what you would expect with the provided distribution range). (Note in my original post I still passed by value not by reference)

Comment: So the copying pretty much takes no time?

Comment: @KellyBundy how do you reach that conclusion? 0.6 ms (copying) vs 2e-8 ms (no copying) is a pretty big difference...

Comment: @KellyBundy It shows copying eats up almost all of the time almost 0.6ms.

Comment: Ah... Your answer doesn't say 2e-8 and makes it sound like 0.6 ms is for your code (which avoids the copy).

Comment: Btw 2e-08 ms is completely unrealistic. Did the compiler optimize the actual calculation away?

Comment: @KellyBundy Fair point, and you were right it was optimized away.
4.2 ms now ;) Updated example.

Comment: Ok so the copying took about 30% of the time? That sounds more realistic :-). Both copying and calculating read the data, difference is writing vs adding, and writing seems simpler (I guess it *could* be slower, but sequential writing is at least cache-friendly).

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes indeed much more realistic, and accumulate gets vectorized quite a bit too https://godbolt.org/z/djxz4cxMW. Thanks for keeping me sharp :)